# magento, problem with login to admin , php error

Tags: magento-1.9, php

when I try to login to the admin panel I get a 500 error

in logs i have this:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 82 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291\n', referer: mysite.com/index.php/admin/
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the value in MB ?

php_value memory_limit 2048M

Also try editing this value in php.ini not Apache.